# NHibernate and AutoMapper

Tags: nhibernate, design-patterns, automapper

What is the best way to run raw SQL against NHibernate,  then push it into List  using AutoMapper?

Example:

```
public virtual List<T> GetList<T>(string mainsql)
{
    IQuery q = GetSession().CreateSQLQuery(mainsql);
    IEnumerable srcAllRows = q.List();
    List<T> targetAllRows = new List<T>();
    *** do AutoMapper thing to get srcAllRow to targetAllRows ***
    return targetAllRows;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with in the **do AutoMapper thing** section

```
public virtual List<T> GetList<T>(string mainSql)
{
    DataTable ldt = new DataTable();        
    StartReader(mainSql); //load a reader with data.

    ldt.Load(reader);
    DataTableReader rdr = ldt.CreateDataReader();

    return (List<T>)Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<T>>(rdr);
}
```